# Best threading strategy for multitasking

Tags: c#, multithreading

I like to get some advise from you experts.
I have a windows program that do this tasks

1. Read in a file (laser scanning data) 10 million points in a thread. Takes ~1min.
   When it has finished.
2. Calculate a GRID in a new thread. Takes ~3min. Then the user can choose different tasks like.
3. Create Bitmap (images) or other objects like elevation contoures. It is made in other threads. Takes ~1min.
4. In the end the user can save the Bitmap or objects to file.

My intention is now to allow a Batch task where the user choose a bunch of files and specify GRID settings and which Bitmap(s) he/she want.

What's the best strategy for this do you think?
I am not advanced programmer, and I have look at the BackgroundWorker. Is it a way if you like to use the new computers with two or more cores?

Comment: openMp is always a good idea for parallel data processing Im not sure if it exist for   c#

Answer (score 0):

Sounds good to me.  I don't understand your whole app, but it sounds like you should be able to some things in parallel.

Can you define a class that can hold the pints and GRID data fo a batch job and has methods to do all these steps?

Can the GRID calculation be split up into sub-tasks that operation on independent segments of the points array, or must all the points be available before any GRID calcuation can start?

Comment: Yes I can define a class for the points and GRID and the methods is ready. One question is - should I keep the original threads in this methods if I have a "Batch" BackgroundWorker. I think its hard to split up the GRID task. You have to have all points.